# how to define same variable for two values using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This question is how to define same variable for two values using python.

```
min_lat = 10
min_lat = lower_right_lat = lower_left_lat
```

I should get the result for both the lower_right_lat and lower_left_lat to be 10.

Comment: If you are trying to set lower_right_lat and lower_left_lat, just reverse the order of your assignment:
`lower_right_lat = lower_left_lat = min_lat`

Comment: @Pathétique: Please put answers in answers, not in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change the order of assignment:

```
lower_right_lat = lower_left_lat = min_lat
```

The statements are evaluated from right to left.